# Is there a function in C that does the same as raw_input in Python?

Tags: python, c, raw-input

Is there a C function that does the same as `raw_input` in Python?

```
#in Python::
x = raw_input("Message Here:")
```

How can I write something like that in C?

**Update::**

I make this, but i get an error ::

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef char * string;

int raw_input(string msg);
string s;
string *d;

main(){
raw_input("Hello, Enter Your Name: ");
d = &s;
printf("Your Name Is: %s", s);

}

int raw_input(string msg){
string name;
printf("%s", msg);
scanf("%s", &name);
*d = name;
return 0;
}
```

and the error is that program run and print the msg, and take what user type by scanf, but then it hangs and exit.. ??

Comment: If you are used to python, you might prefer C++, why do you especially want C?

Comment: because i'm studding it in the university :),, and i really want to learn it :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write one pretty easily, but you'll want to be careful about buffer overflows:

```
void raw_input(char *prompt, char *buffer, size_t length)
{
    printf("%s", prompt);
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(buffer, length, stdin)
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
char x[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH];
raw_input("Message Here:", x, sizeof x);
```

You may want to add some error checking, and so on.

Comment: fflush(stdout); what this mean ??

Comment: @Rami, a lot of `printf()` implementions don't actually flush the output until a newline character.  If you want the prompt to be on the same line, you have to force the system to flush the output.

Answer (score 4):

The [POSIX.1-2008](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/mindex.html) standard  specifies the function [getline](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), which will dynamically (re)allocate memory to make space for a line of arbitrary length.

This has the benefit over `gets` of being invulnerable to overflowing a fixed buffer, and the benefit over `fgets` of being able to handle lines of any length, at the expense of being a potential DoS if the line length is longer than available heap space.

Prior to POSIX 2008 support, Glibc exposed this as a GNU extension as well.

```
char *input(const char *prompt, size_t *len) {
    char *line = NULL;
    if (prompt) {
        fputs(prompt, stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    getline(&line, len, stdin);
    return line;
}
```

Remember to `free(line)` after you're done with it.

---

To read into a fixed-size buffer, use `fgets` or `scanf("%*c")` or similar; this allows you to specify a maximum number of characters to scan, to prevent overflowing a fixed buffer.  (There is no reason to ever use `gets`, it is unsafe!)

```
char line[1024] = "";
scanf("%1023s", line);      /* scan until whitespace or no more space */
scanf("%1023[^\n]", line);  /* scan until newline or no more space */
fgets(line, 1024, stdin);   /* scan including newline or no more space */
```

Comment: Care to explain your bland assertion that fgets is unsafe?
It is not perfect, but unless you pass the wrong parameters I would hardly say it is *unsafe*.

Comment: Oh.  Obviously I was thinking of `gets`.  `fgets` has a length parameter and thus is not vulnerable in the same way.  I'll fix that up.

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf` to print your prompt, then use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) to read the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer seems complex to me.

I think this is little easier:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
   char array[100];

   printf("Type here: ");
   gets(array);
   printf("You said: %s\n", array);

   return 0;
}
```