# Different behaviour when opening Excel and Word in python using win32com.client.dispatch function

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I'm a new beginner in python development.

I'm trying to practice win32com.client module, and there's some error that is very confused.

first, I tried it.

```
import win32com.client
word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True
```

Clearly, it works well. So I tried below.

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
```

It works like Word but closed very a few seconds later. I don't know why it happens.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you running the script or debugging it ?

Comment: I always use `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')` can you test if that leads to the same problem?

Comment: @ds4940 there's no error script or log because it cleary run well, but only excel was closed very soon

Comment: @tst Thank, you. This method can be one of the solution to me bro. It works well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like behaviour of Word is not as straight as it's supposed to be. Word application have to be garbage collected by [gc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) module, but it isn't the case. You can get a superficial view terminating execution using `input` in interpreter:

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
app.Visible = True
input('deleting reference...')
# deleting reference forces gc to clear Excel
# though Word remains uncollected even thereafter
del app
input('Exit...')
```

Python memory management is quite complicated and it becomes a problem when Python is embedded into other applications. Some useful information about garbage collection you can find in article [How does Python manage memory?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-does-python-manage-memory.htm) (may be outdated but could be useful for common understanding) or in Python's docs [Memory Management](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html).

The good approach is to close it explicitly using `Quit` method to properly release application from memory:

```
app.Quit()
```

Comment: It works well. Thank you. I wondered that I learned the input method is like 'scanf' in C language, isn't it? But in your code, It works like 'printf', right?

Comment: @ShinMin-Young `input` in Python also reads the reply. I guess it's like `printf` and then `fgets` in C. Info about it could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496857/is-there-a-function-in-c-that-does-the-same-as-raw-input-in-python/29636153